# DOM Array manipulation

Tags: javascript

The array I'm trying to manipulate

```
const choices = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("choice-text"));
```

when I console.log this I get this

[image: console.log from choices]

I'm trying to access that p.choice-text, choice-text is a class in my html btw and all I want to do is remove a class from the classList. I can't for the life of me figure it out any help would be appreciated.

Update:
tried

`choices.forEach(p => {
  p.classList.remove("unwanted-class");
})`

did not work

Comment: `choices.forEach(x=>x.classList.remove("choice-text"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `forEach` loop to loop through the elements and do whatever you want then:

```
const choices = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("choice-text"));

choices.forEach((p) => {
    p.classList.remove('another-class');
}
```

You could alternatively use a for loop without having to convert the result to an array:

```
const choices = document.getElementsByClassName("choice-text");

for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
  choices[i].classList.remove('another-class');
}
```

Comment: Ah I tried this but it didn't work the classList still has the class I wanted to remove

Comment: @Nen Then include the code you used, because this worked for me.

Comment: Ah mb I forgot to add the parentElement bit I'm sorry for taking up your time. Thanks a lot Mr Geek